# Aurelia-Validation - Clarity on object validation w/addObject()

Tags: aurelia

I'm attempting to manually validate an object which is updated via a customEvent.

`//home.html
<type-ahead change.delegate="updateValue($event.detail, true/false)"></type-ahead>`

I have two of the above elements, which I want to assign to the properties of `origin` and `destination` based on a boolean value.

I also want to validate both of these properties against the same custom rule, which I've defined in `setupValidation` on my viewmodel below.

Both of these are objects, that need some complex validation (I've simplified it for demonstration purposes), so I've used `.ensureObject()` and manually add both of these objects to the validation controller.

I would expect that I would only have to add the objects once (during my initial `setupValidation()`, but I've found that I have to remove, and then re-add the object to the validation controller whenever it changes.

If you look at `updateValue(...)`, you'll see that I'm expecting `this.destination` to validate to the updated object, but I'm seeing my results still be `null` on validation. However, `this.origin` does update and the validation succeeds (as I'm manually updating the controller).

I would expect not to have to manually update the controller. Is this expected?

```
//home.ts
@autoinject
export class Home {
    origin = null;
    destination = null;

    private controller: ValidationController;

    public canSubmit: boolean = false;
    public error: string;

    private rules;

    constructor(controllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory) {
        this.controller = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
        this.controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
    }

    bind() {
        this.setupValidation();
    }

    private validate() {
        this.controller.validate()
            .then(results => {
                this.canSubmit = results.valid;
            });
    }

    private setupValidation() {
        ValidationRules.customRule(
            'rule1',
            (value) => { 
                if(value.property && value.property.length === 3)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            },
            `\${$displayName} must be 3 characters long`
        );

        this.rules = ValidationRules
            .ensureObject()
                .required()
                .satisfiesRule('rule1')
            .rules;

        this.controller.addObject(this.origin, this.rules);
        this.controller.addObject(this.destination, this.rules);
    }

    updateValue(newValue, isOrigin) {
        if(isOrigin) {
            this.controller.removeObject(this.origin);
            this.origin = newValue;
            this.controller.addObject(this.origin, this.rules);
        }
        else
            this.destination = newValue;

        this.validate();
    }
}
```

Thank you, let me know if there are any additional details needed.

Comment: Interesting development - my results array values for one of my objects. I would expect it to have `ValidateResult` for `this.origin` & `this.destination`.